# iFrame sagepay low profile?

Tags: opayo

has anyone used this before in .Net? The documentation on how to implement this is shockingly poor.

I can connect to sage and see a card payment screen but not using an iFrame?

If I was using the asp.net integration kit for example...which page would I put the iFrame on?

Anyone done this before?

Comment: [This document explains it all](http://www.sagepay.com/sites/default/files/pdf/user_guides/sagepayserverprotocolandintegrationguidelinesv3.0_0.pdf) you just need to read it properly. You must first register a payment to obtain the correct URL to use for the iframe

Comment: @musefan That link is dead.

Comment: @musefan can you repost that link please

Comment: @byronyasgur: Unfortunately, it's too long ago that I no longer remember which exact document it was. Might want to have a [look through these though](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-inframe-integration-documents)

Comment: Thanks I know .... found [this](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1161/download-document/SERVERProtocolandIntegrationGuidelinesV3%200.pdf) ( which might have been the file you linked ) .... there's a newer version in that last link you shared if that's the one ... yes haven't read it properly yet and glad to know it's "the one" because I'd hate to wade through 70 pages and find I need to read another one. Sagepay will need to get their docs sorted for my 2c

Comment: Actually I had a quick look through that doc and I don't see any example code in there so I must have it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation includes the appendices for the protocols - search for something like "sagepay direct integration guidelines pdf"

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1166/download-document/DIRECTProtocolandIntegrationGuidelinesV3%200%20%281%29.pdf

The appendices list the transactions you'll need to handle.